# how to remove the customer login page text

Tags: magento2, layout, customer-login

how do I remove the text? or how should I overwrite existing xml file?
Please help. I did try to override the file, but not work. Not sure I place the file into correct place or not. If I update XML, seems I have to run the setup:upgrade right?

Please help, thanks

[image]

Comment: you want to remove using css ??? and share your xml file path...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy file this path :-

```
magento_root/vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/layout/customer_account_login.xml
```

paste your custom theme

```
magento_root/app/design/frontend/Theme_Vendor/Theme_Name/Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account_login.xml
```

After paste your custom theme you run some command like :-

```
remove var/cache folder
remove var/view_preprocessed folder
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento c:c
php bin/magento c:f
```

Override your xml file after your change you hide the code.

**2.)** You want to remove using css.So find customer login text class and apply css `display:none;`.

**EX:-**

```
.customer.login.text{
display:none;
}
```

Hope this help you

Thanks ...

Comment: I still don't know why after I copy and paste the xml to the theme location and ran those command, remove var/cache folder
remove var/view_preprocessed folder
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento c:c
php bin/magento c:f, still not showing the update. Any hints? thanks

Comment: override xml file is not working ???

Comment: Yes,  I don't why？

Comment: you run command again and first your remove two folder and second you run setup comamnd and third `php bin/magento s:s:d -f` and continue `php bin/magento c:c` `php bin/magento c:f`

Comment: I just try the process again, before I did it, I reboot my server, remove 2 folders, run magento setup, and then run the php bin/magento s:s:d -d and then run the c:c and c:f after. Even I use the Google chorme incognito mode, the "Customer Login" text still showing. I am sure I place the correct file to the right folder. The new duplicated and modified  customer_account_login.xml seems not taken any affect

Comment: I read from some group, do I need to add dependency ? if Yes, which file I should add dependency ? thanks

Comment: I am sorry, may be something wrong with my magento, I reboot the server and repeat the process again, and now its work. Thankyou for helping me out. Should be some problem with the Magento setup upgrade